# Derangement formula; proof by induction

Tags: combinatorics, induction

Proof by induction that
$
d_{n}=nd_{n-1}+(-1)^{n}
$
where $d_{n}$ is number of $n$-element derangements.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any more detailed thoughts or questions about what you need to do?

Comment: Look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056610/combinatorial-argument-for-recursive-formula) and its answers; you can use its recurrence in the induction step of your argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the derangements of the first $n-1$ elements (from $1$ to $n-1$) and swap one of them ($x$) with $n$. Note that $n$ will never be in the original position of $x$, so we need to add that case. First case: $(n-1)d_{n-1}$ (there are $n-1$ possible choices of $x$ and $d_{n-1}$ derangements). Second case: $(n-1)d_{n-2}$ (same thing, but without $x$ and $n$ there are $d_{n-2}$ derangements). Use the recursion formula do add both cases:
$$\begin{align}
d_{n-1} &= (n-1)d_{n-2}+(-1)^{n-1}\\
d_{n-2} &= \frac{1}{n-1}\left[d_{n-1}+(-1)^n\right]\\
d_{n} &= (n-1)d_{n-1}+(n-1)d_{n-2}\\
 & = (n-1)d_{n-1}+\frac{n-1}{n-1}\left[d_{n-1}+(-1)^n\right]\\
 &= nd_{n-1}+(-1)^n
\end{align}$$
Finally, just show that the recursion formula works for the initial cases $d_0 = 0$ and $d_1 = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**
The number of derangements is given by
$$d_n = n! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.$$

To prove your relationship by induction, show that

- it is correct for the base case $n=1$, i.e. that $d_1 = 1 d_0 + (-1)^1$ by plugging in.
- it is correct in the inductive step; i.e., assuming that this is true for all $k=1, \ldots n-1$, prove that this is true for $k=n$.

Can you finish this?