# Number of ways of shuffling cards such that $i^{th}$ card is not in the $i^{th}$ position

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Suppose we have $n$ cards. How many ways of shuffling do we have such that card $i$ is not in the $i$ slot.

**I thought about doing:**

$n$ choices to pick card $1$, $(n-1)$ possible places to put it

$n-1$ choices to pick card $2$, $(n-2)$ possibilities

$2$ choices to pick Card $n$, $1$ possibility to put it in the deck

Comment: You are asking about [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: Thanks :) , I'll have a look

Comment: Notice that if you put card $1$ in position $2$, you now have $n-1$ places you can put card $2$. That makes the formula not so simple. But the link to "derangements" should help.

Comment: See [these](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056610/combinatorial-argument-for-recursive-formula) two [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058157/derangement-formula-proof-by-induction) on recursive formulas for $d_n$.

Comment: Thanks for you answers I maganed to solve it, the articles were helpful :)