# Permutation & Combination of letters

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can one put 5 letters into 5 envelopes correctly if 1 letter alone should go into the correct Envelope?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the question if it's from a book or something? I can't understand the question.

Comment: I am Sorry... See if u can understand now

Comment: @mihir: a picture of the letters and the envelopes?

Comment: Is your question that you have five letters: $a,b,c,d,e$, and five envelopes $A,B,C,D,E$, and you send one letter to each of the envelopes in some manner, say $\begin{pmatrix} A&B&C&D&E\\a&c&d&e&b\end{pmatrix}$ in such a way that only one envelope received the correct letter?

Comment: @miracle173, what do you mean? Since the original post wasn't worded properly, I couldn't understand the question, and that's why I asked him to post a picture of the question if it's from a book

Comment: @mihir: A picture of a text is not a good idea. This is not wanted here. He can type the original text to this post. If he needs assistance in formatting the text he will get help here. If one selects the context menu (right mouse button)  'Show -Math -> TeX Commands' of a TeX graphic, one can see the TeX command that generates this formula. TeX commands must be preceded and terminated by a dollar character (or two dollar characters is it should be positioned in a separate line)

Answer (score 1):

Its a typical example of dearrangement the general formula is $D_n=n![1-\frac{1}{1!}+..-..+\frac{(-1^{n})}{n!}]$ so here dearrangements are 4 so plug in the value as $n=4$  and  you get answer as $9$ . Hope it helps you. But from next time please share your effort!

Comment: You also have to select which of the five envelopes will receive the correct letter.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't want to give out the answer to anyone who may be trying to work on this problem, think of the analogous problem: How any ways can you place 4 letters into 4 envelopes so that none are in their correct envelope?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, choose the letter to be posted correctly in 5 ways.

Then derange the other 4. D(n) can be derived by inclusion exclusion principle (it is a simple exercise) as 
$$ D(4) = 9.$$

Therefore, Number of ways = 5*9=45

Comment: Could u use normal permuation and explain...

Comment: To find D(n) use exclusion -inclusion as I have mentioned or the link to a proof is here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Examples   and  for a recursive proof http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056610/combinatorial-argument-for-recursive-formula